# Fixed header with dropdown menu which moves the content

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

Here's what happens when unfixed and it's the behaviour I want but I want navbar to be fixed[image]

Here's what happens when fixed: it doesn't move the content (it is behind this dropdown)[image]

```
// scss for the nav
.filterbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
    width: 100%;
// for info section
.filters-info {
    margin-top: 110px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

How to fix this? (margin-bottom didn't help). I have two ideas: 1. to get toggleFilterbar prop and to change the styling based on this 2. to make the nav position absolute and then to change it to fixed. However, I guess there must be a simplier css way to fix this

Answer (score 0):

**Give**  `position:relative;` to  `.filters-info`

and

**Replace** `margin-top: 110px;` to  `top: 110px;`